# Continuous Time Jumps In {0, 1}

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, poisson-process

How would one define a continuous time stochastic process which jumps between between zero and one with intensity $\lambda$?

More specifically, I would like to define a process $X_t = Y_t + J_t$ such that $dY_t = \mu dt + \sigma dB_t$ and $J_t$ jumps between zero and one with intensity $\lambda$. I would like to be able to define $dX_t$, but am having trouble formulating the stochastic integral for $J_t$.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at resolving this problem (anyone confirming or disputing my intuition would be great):

Define $X_t$ and $Y_t$ as above. Define $J_t \in \{0, 1\}$ as a stochastic process which jumps with intensity $\lambda$. This implies a jump size of $\lambda$ if $J_t = 0$ and $-\lambda$ if $J_t = 1$.

The [expected change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma#Poisson_jump_processes) in $J_t$ is $\mathbb{E}dJ_t = \lambda(1\{J_t = 0\}  - 1\{J_t = 1\})dt$, where $1\{\cdot\}$ denotes the indicator function.

$dX_t = dY_t + dJ_t = \mu dt + \sigma dB_t + dJ_t$

Taking expectations gives

$\mathbb{E} dX_t = \left[\mu + \lambda(1\{J_t = 0\}  - 1\{J_t = 1\})\right]dt$

Comment: It implies a jump of size $1$ if $J_t=0$ and $-1$ if $J_t = 1.$

Comment: Does it not imply a jump size of $\lambda$?

Comment: No why would it? $\lambda$ is to do with the rate, not the size

Comment: Yes, but the jump size is referring to the jump in $X$, not in $J$... I think I see your point, but this is exactly my issue, I'm really unsure about how to work with jump processes.

Comment: Sorry for using $X$ in a conflicting way in my answer. Assuming we're talking about your $X$, since $X=Y+J$ the jumps in $X$ are the same as the jumps in $J$, which have size $\pm1$ by your definition. $\lambda$ is the rate of jumps, so would relate to the expected value and thus the drift required to compensate (if turning it into a martingale) but has nothing to do with the size of the jumps.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_t$ be a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$. Then the process $$ J_t = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & \mbox{$X_t$ is an odd integer} \\ 0 &\mbox{otherwise} \end{array}\right.$$ fits your description.

As for how to handle the process, pdevar's approach of thinking of it as a state-dependent jump size could help. So writing an SDE like $$ dJ_t = f(J_t) dX_t$$ where $X_t$ is a Poisson processes and $f(x) = 1$ when $x$ is zero and $f(x)=-1$ when $x$ is one.

Not sure writing a better-formulated SDE is gonna help with your problem. An analysis of $J_t$'s distribution and linearity will, though.